# Array sort() sorted the actual array list after assigning to another array as well

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

Result holds dynamic value in array but after sorting the result also get sorted but I don't want it to get sorted. But after sorting its also get sorted. Why is that?

```
$scope.arreyList = result;
var sorted_arr = $scope.arreyList.sort();
$scope.countRowSame = [];
for (var i = 0; i < sorted_arr.length - 1; i++) {
    if (sorted_arr[i + 1].SupplierId == sorted_arr[i].SupplierId) {
        $scope.countRowSame.push(sorted_arr[i].SupplierId);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`sort`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.11) sorts the array **in place**. So this line:

```
var sorted_arr = $scope.arreyList.sort();
```

sorts the `$scope.arreyList`, and returns a reference to that same array. It *doesn't* create a sorted copy of the array.

If you want to make a copy and sort that, use [`slice`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.10):

```
var sorted_arr = $scope.arreyList.slice(0).sort();
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to @Crowder's answer you can use `angular.copy()` to clone the array.

```
$scope.arreyList = angular.copy(result);
var sorted_arr = $scope.arreyList.sort();
```